# Get modified date of remote file

Tags: java, android, httpconnection, last-modified

Is there some way to get modified date of [this file](http://www.poznan.pl/featureserver/featureserver.cgi/mpk_linie)?

I want to check the data every day and download it only if has changed, I tried with `HttpURLConnection` and `con.getHeaderFields()` but no results:

> {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Age=[158], Cache-Control=[max-age=7200], Connection=[close], Content-Length=[235409], Content-Type=[text/plain], Date=[Wed, 19 Dec 2012 10:00:52 GMT], Expires=[Wed, 19 Dec 2012 11:58:13 GMT], Server=[Apache/2], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1355911252001], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1355911251975]}

**Is there a better way of getting an md5 hash and compare it with a local file?**

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is no general way to get the modified date of a URL. Computing the MD5 hash of the HTTP response body and comparing that against the local file is the best way.